# Buildozer spec package.domain name uppercase issue

Tags: android, kivy, apk, buildozer

I'm hoping someone can help me explain why when I specify a package.domain name in the Buildozer.spec file that has an uppercase, buildozer changes it to lowercase during the compilation.

For example my package.name is *flute* and my package.domain name is *com.Anderson* so I expect the final APK to have a package name of *com.Anderson.flute* but when the APK is finally built/compiled, the package name is *com.anderson.flute*

Is there a way to fix this? I am using Google colab to compile the APK which was developed using Python and Kivy.

Comment: Domain names are case insensitive.

Comment: I thought so too until I tried publishing to Google Play and it specifically told me that the package name is not the same. The only difference is the capital letter "A".